Change of variable in inner integral
I am currently reading "Mathematical Statistics & Data Analysis" of John A. Rice. The following on p.97 is unclear to me:

Let $Z = X + Y$. Supposing that $X$ and $Y$ are continuous random variables, we first find the CDF of $Z$ and then differentiate to find the density.

$$\begin{align}
F_Z(z) &= \iint_{R_z} f(x, y) \, dx \, dy \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{z-x} f(x, y) \, dy \right) dx
\end{align}
$$

In the inner integral, we make the change of variables $y = v - x$ to obtain:

$$\begin{align}
F_Z(z) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{z} f(x, v - x) \, dv \right) dx \\
&
= \int_{-\infty}^{z} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x, v - x) \, dx \right) dv
\end{align}$$
Can you explain why the change of variables is necessary? Why is it problematic if we integrate over y and then plug in the upper boundary $z-x$? Maybe a concrete example where things crash would help. Thanks!

To exchange two integrals you need to have no dependency of the domain from the variables (in this case no $x$'s in the endpoints of the interval). In addition to the formal reasons, if you tried to exchange the integrals, it wouldn't make any sense to integrate in $\text d y$ with a domain depending from $x$, where $x$ is just the variable used to compute the integral inside (so not a parameter).
In this particular case the substitution actually eliminate this dependence and it also determines the formula for the density, which is
$$g(v)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,v-x)\text d x.$$

Hi Matteo, thank you so much! So if I understand correctly, one main reason is that, we want to exchange the integral in a later stage by applying Fubinis Theorem. There is where the x causes troubles? Because the x would remain, even after the second integration and that is not possible?

Yes, you are correct.
